# Deployment "tiller" exceeded its progress deadline

Tags: openshift, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to install tiller server to an Openshift project

Helm/tiller version: 2.9.0

My project name: paytiller

At step 3, executing this command (mentioned as per this document - https://www.openshift.com/blog/getting-started-helm-openshift)

```
oc rollout status deployment tiller
```

I get this error:

```
error: deployment "tiller" exceeded its progress deadline
```

I'm not clear on what's the error message or could find any logs.
Any idea why this error?
If this doesn't work, what are the other suggestions for templating in Openshift?

---

EDIT

```
oc get events

Events:
  Type     Reason   Age                   From                     Message
  ----     ------   ----                  ----                         ---
  Warning  Failed   14m (x5493 over 21h)  kubelet, example.com  Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling  9m (x255 over 21h)    kubelet, example.com  pulling image "gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller:v2.9.0"
  Normal   BackOff  4m (x5537 over 21h)   kubelet, example.com  Back-off pulling image "gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller:v2.9.0"
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the output for `oc get events` for the namespace where you see the error?

Comment: @Simon, I have added that as edit

Comment: I know it will not answer your question/problem, but if you deploy tiller for using Helm 2.x, maybe you could consider switching to Helm 3.x as it does not requires any setup on the Openshift/Kubernetes side.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the permissions on our OpenShift platform. We didn't have access to download from open-source directly.

We tried to add kubernetes-helm as a docker image to our organization repository and then we were able to pull the image to OpenShift project. It is working now. But still, we didn't get any clue of the issue from the logs.

Answer (score 0):

The status `ImagePullBackOff` tells you that this image `gcr.io/kubernetes-helm/tiller:v2.9.0` could not be pulled from the container registry. So your OpenShift node cannot pull that image for some reason. **This is often due to network proxies, a non-existing image (not the issue here) or other restrictions in the (corporate) network.**

You can use `oc describe pod <pod that shows ImagePullBackOff>` to find out the more detailed error message that may help you further.

Also, note that the blog post you linked is from 2017, which is very old. Here is a more current version: [Build Kubernetes Operators from Helm Charts in 5 steps](https://www.openshift.com/blog/build-kubernetes-operators-from-helm-charts-in-5-steps)
.